# Prove $T(W)\subset W$ if and only if $T^*(W^\perp)\subset W^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ with $V$ a vector space of finite dimension and $W\subset V$. Prove $T(W)\subset W$ if and only if $T^*(W^\perp)\subset W^\perp$

My work:

$\leftarrow$  Let $f\in T^*(W^\perp)$ then $T^*(f)\in W^\perp$ this implies $\{T^*(f)=0 \forall f\in W^*\}$ then $f\in W^*$

In consequence,   $T^*(W^\perp)\subset W^\perp$

$\rightarrow$ Let $w\in T(W)$ then $T(w)\in W$

I'm stuck here, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

If $T(W)\subseteq W$ it follows that $T^*(W^\bot)\subseteq W^\bot$ as $<T^*(v),w> = <v,T(w)>=0$ for all $w\in W, v\in W^\bot$ since $T(w)\in W$.

Conversely suppose that $T^*(W^\bot)\subseteq W^\bot$. One has to show that $T(W)\subseteq W$. Since $W = (W^\bot)^\bot$ it suffices to show that for all $w\in W$ it holds that $<T(w),v>=0\quad \forall v\in W^\bot$.
But $<T(w),v>=<w, T^*(v)>$ which is zero since $T^*(v)\in W^\bot$ and $w\in W$.

Comment: I dont see this $<T^*(v),w> = <v,T(w)>=0$ can you explain me this? thanks

Comment: Simply by the definition of adjoint for the first equality.

Comment: Like user284331 said the first equation is just the definition of the adjoint operator. The second follows since $T(w)\in W$ and $v\in W^\bot$ from the definition of $W^\bot$.

Comment: Note that since $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space it admits an inner product (identify a basis with the standard basis of some $K^n$ and take the standard inner product). Every functional $\lambda \in V^*$ is of the form $\lambda(v)=<w,v>\quad \forall v\in V$ for some $w\in V$.

Answer (score 2):

For $w\in W^{\perp}$ and $v\in W$, then $Tv\in W$, and hence $\left<T^{\ast}w,v\right>=\left<w,Tv\right>=0$.